# Ошибка в коде php настройка smarty

Tags: php

Здравствуйте нужна помощь, выдает ошибку на данный код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\OpenServer\domains\MyInternetShop\Config\config.php on line 25

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если версия PHP меньше 8, то в каждом из методов у переданного аргумента символы до двоеточия и сами двоеточия - лишние и надо их удалить